# Mass audio encoder

Tags: software-recommendation, encoding

I have a few thousand FLAC files which I would like to transcode to OGG Vorbis, but I can't find any suitable tools for the job. To name a few I have tried so far and why they are unsuitable: oggenc is single-threaded and would require me to automate it myself, mencoder requires the input to also contain video, and abcde assumes the input is a CD.

The ideal tool should be multi-threaded, and support inputing multiple files located in different directories simultaneously. CLI or GUI makes no matter.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Have you tried Sound Converter? Its installable via the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @Weylin That's perfect, thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks man, I was going too but I was in a rush. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out SoundConverter. It can encode to nearly every format as well as convert multiple files at once from different locations. It is installable from the Ubuntu Software Center or by running this code in the terminal:

`Sudo apt-get install soundconverter`

[image: A screenshot of SoundConverter]

However you must open the preferences menu to change output format as well as output location and other miscellaneous settings. Hope that helps. 
And Thanks.